# Porqué me sale este error mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysql

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Software\registroComentarios.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Software\registroComentarios.php on line 44

mi Funcion Registro

function registros($Documento,$Asunto,$Mensaje)
{

```
require_once "conectar.php";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comentario (idDocumento,Asunto,Mensaje) VALUES ('$Documento','$Asunto','$Mensaje')";

     if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    {           
        echo "New record created successfully";
          header('Location: materias.php');

    } else 
        {
                echo "no se pudieron guardar los datos " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
         }
```

}

Comment: Como bien te dice el error - la variable **$conn** no está definida. No has mostrado todo el código de la función pero esta variable no la recibes como parámetro y tampoco la defines en la función.

Comment: en el Archivo conexion la Tengo

Comment: function registros($Documento,$Asunto,$Mensaje)
{
    
  
    require_once "conectar.php";
  global $conn;
  $sql = "INSERT INTO comentario (idDocumento,Asunto,Mensaje) VALUES ('$Documento','$Asunto','$Mensaje')";

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
  {         
     echo "New record created successfully";
     header('Location: materias.php');
          
  } else 
   {
           echo "no se pudieron guardar los datos " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta declarar la variable $conn, si la tienes declarada, pero fuera de la función, para usarla dentro debes usar

```
<?php
registros($Documento,$Asunto,$Mensaje){
  global $conn;
  ...
}
?>
```

Si la función está dentro de una clase y $conn es una variable de la clase, entonces:

```
mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql)
```

Comment: La puse Global dentro de la conexion.php y me funcionó, ¡¡ muchas Gracias¡¡